# Can I use the same Certificate I use for SSL, to sign my AuthRequests for SAML - Spring Boot SAML SSO

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml

I have SSL on my site, from a CA. The IdP system I'm using will not allow self-signed certs. Can I use the exact same cert I use for SSL to sign my AuthRequests? Or do I need another cert for that? They're the same kind of cert I imagine, right? Both x509?

Thank you!

Comment: IdP software that does not allow self-signed certificates for SAML response signing or encryption is badly broken. If possible use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same certificate, since it had been issued for your application.